# How to handle errors using `.catch` in promises

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise, es6-promise, feathersjs

I want to continue code execution when my promises do not have errors, If there are any errors however, I do not want to proceed. How do I gracefully handle this case ?

Eg.

```
/* start of REST call */
const resultA = fetchThings()
    .then(things => returnSomeResult(things))
    .then(...)
    ...
    .catch(err => throw err);  // cannot proceed computation if there is error
    
const resultB = fetchOtherThings()
    .then(otherTings => returnOtherResult(otherThings))
    .then(...)
    ...
    .catch(err => throw err); // cannot proceed if there is error

const resultC = Promise.all([resultA, resultB]) => { // do other stuff }

// return resultC from REST call if successful
```

When an error occurs in either of the results, I am getting a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` on the terminal. It states that `This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with a .catch()`. I suspect it is because I am throwing the error inside the catch block.

However, I don't want the code to proceed when there is an error from either resultA or resultB.

How can I better handle this scenario of mine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you're not handling errors thrown by `Promise.all()`, which will be rejected if any of the promises it's handling will be rejected.

So you need to catch errors there as well:

```
Promise.all(…).then(…).catch(e => …)
```

FWIW, your `catch()`'s are superfluous:

```
.catch(err => throw err)
```

You're catching errors that were thrown and rethrowing them, which isn't necessary (they will be caught by `.catch()` that you'll attach to `Promise.all()`).

Comment: I realised also that I needed to put the await expression in `Promise.all`.